# Learning Laravel blade standalone

Tags: model-view-controller, laravel-blade

I'm pretty new with blade template building in **Laravel** and I'm planning to use it as standalone. What's the best way to learn blade template building perhaps for standalone?

What's the different components of blade template building and what's the data flow?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use without Laravel, then you could try my library.

https://github.com/EFTEC/BladeOne

Its stand alone, only one class and no dependencies (and mit license)

The docs about blade is here

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade

The data flow is simple:

1. add all the libraries and dependencies.
2. creates all the
   variables, collects information from $_POST,$_GET and such.
3. Load
   and do all the operations, such as loading from the database,
   inserting, doing some operation.
4. And finally, call the template and send the variables.   The template must be called at the end of your script.  Always.